# OutOfMemoryError when trying to add elements from a B+Tree to an ArrayList

Tags: java, recursion, tree-traversal, b-tree, b-plus-tree

I'm attempting to traverse through a B+ Tree and add the elements from the leaves into an ArrayList with the following code:

```
public void toArrayList(Node node){
       Node currentNode = node;
       if(currentNode instanceof InnerNode){
               InnerNode inner = (InnerNode) currentNode;
               int i = 0;
               int temp = inner.children.length;
               while(i < temp){
                   currentNode = inner.children[i];
                   toArrayList(currentNode);
                   i++;
               }


           }
       if(currentNode instanceof LeafNode){
               LeafNode leaf = (LeafNode) currentNode;
               int j = 0;
               int temp = leaf.values.length;
               while(j < temp){
                   if(leaf.values[j] != null) {
                       retArray.add(leaf.values[j]);
                   }
                   j++;
               }

           }
    }
```

What it does is it checks if the node is an instance of an Inner Node or a Leaf Node. If it is an Inner Node it recursively calls the function with each of its children. If it is a Leaf Node then it will add the values into the ArrayList. However while running this fucntion I end up getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Is there a way to make my code more efficient or should I look to take a different approach to this method?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your tree structure has a few million elements in it, what's going on here is that some InnerCode contains itself, and thus this code keeps going forever, or, at least, until your `retArray` fills up.

Also note that this code will add a leaf node twice if it's the last child of an inner node. I strongly suggest you don't overwrite locals like this. Also, for loops are just more compact here (note that making this code smaller is not going to make any difference *at all* for memory issues; OOMError refers to the heap, and locals don't live there).